# Pass values to another component in React Final Form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-final-form

Using [Wizard form example](https://codesandbox.io/s/km2n35kq3v) to create component with current input values. Strangely enough, components are identical, but only `Wizard` component returns object with initial values, when `Slider` component returns empty object. Most important, is it possible to keep values updated?

```
 class Slider extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {
            page: 0,
            values: props.initialValues || {}
          }
        }


        render() {
           const { values } = this.state
           console.log(values);
          return (
            <div></div>
          )
        }
      }
```

**UPDATE**

My problem is input type range styling: https://codesandbox.io/s/w65rq7ok4w. Trying to create a component that would return div with dynamically changing width that would depend from input type range value e.g. [Input Range progress with css gradient](http://codepen.io/duplich/pen/qjYQEZ)

Comment: Do you have an example of your instantiations?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh example is identical https://codesandbox.io/s/km2n35kq3v just wanted to create additional component that would return current input values.

Comment: Do you have it this way in your code at point of initialization? `<Slider
      initialValues={{ employed: true, stooge: 'larry' }}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >`

Comment: @TheoWittkovskiy take a look at the updated question, it is styling issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `parent component` of all your child forms which contain state. Here is example:

```
 class Slider extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     page: 0,
     values: props.initialValues || {
       employed: false,
       otherKey: "otherValue"
     }
   }

   this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
   this.nexPage = this.nexPage.bind(this);
 }


 handleUpdate(nextValues) {
   this.setState({ values: { ...this.state.values, nextValues} });
 }

 nextPage() {
   this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
 }

 renderForm(){
   const { values } = this.state;
   switch(page) {
     case 3: return <ThirdForm {...values}/>;
     case 1: return <AnotherForm {...values} />;
     default: return <FirstForm {...values}/>;
   }
 }

  render() {
   const { values } = this.state
   console.log(values);
   return (
     <div>
      {this.renderForm()}
     </div>
   )
  }
}
```

So your values store in on place, and changes only by `handleUpdate` method parents component.

Parent component will be pass it data to child component when child component `onChange` method fires.
Here is example(other forms same...):

```
class FirstForm extends React.Component {

 handleChange(e) {
   this.props.handleUpdate({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 }

 handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.nextPage();
 }

 render() {
   const { value1 } = this.props;
   return(
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
       <input name="value1" value={value1} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
     </form>
   );
 }
}
```

Set up attributes `name` is a key and `value` as value to your inputs and pass it to parent component through childs `handleChange` method and parents `handleUpdate` method.

When submit fires, you need to change page by parent method `nextPage`.

## Edit:

For input width styling(range min[0] max[100]):

```
render() {
 const { values: { rangeValue } } = this.state;  
 return(
  <div style={{ width: `${rangeValue}%` }}></div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but to make it clear, my problem is input type range styling. Trying to create a component that would return div with dynamically changing width that would depend from input type range value e.g. https://codepen.io/duplich/pen/qjYQEZ

Comment: o.O I edit answer for range styling, if i truly  understand, maybe its help, gl

Comment: tried to understand your solution and recreated working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/w65rq7ok4w . Maybe situation will be clearer now, could you elaborate on case?